# Выбрать из XElement определенные элементы

Tags: c#, xml

Обрабатываю XML большого размера, для этого использую `XmlReader` и `XElement`. Загружаю в `XElement`поддерево, мне необходимо вернуть имена и значения элементов первого уровня вложенности. Пробую так

```
XmlReader Subtree = reader.ReadSubtree();
XElement xElement = XElement.Load(Subtree);
foreach (var elem in xElement.Elements())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Elem name {0} value {1}", elem.Name, elem.Value);
}
```

Но если в элементе есть свое поддерево он мне возвращает сцепленное значение из всех значений поддерева.

```
<a>
   <b>
      <c>val1</c>
      <d>val2</d>
   </b>
   <e>val3</e>
   <f>val4</f>
</a>
```

В данном случае он вернет `b` `val1val2`

Comment: Так а что вы хотите чтоб он вам возвращал для таких элементов?

Comment: Какой нибудь маркер что там поддерево

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [`XElement.HasElements()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.haselements(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine(
    "Elem name {0} value {1}", 
    elem.Name, 
    elem.HasElements() ? "contains subtree" : elem.Value);
```